# python altervative to "eval" for converting the string to object

Tags: python, eval

I have a file that contains string representation of an object in python, like the following example format

```
[(170,572,380,114,-17746,[('F',3),('b',19)]),
(170,222,128,40,-7086,[('F',3),('b',4),('g',2)]),
(170,184,52,18,-5776,[('F',3),('b',1),('g',1),('C',2)])]
```

I have been using eval to convert it to a python object, but it takes very very long when there are 1M items.

Is there any other better way to make it faster? or any other approach which could speed it up?

Kind Regard

Comment: Change the format which your data is saved to the file?

Comment: Might be worth trying saving and loading the data using pandas or something.

Comment: You could try adding `item_list = ` at the start of the first line, then importing your file.

Answer (score 0):

You have `pickle` and `json` to play with. JSON has limited data types, so you will have your tuples converted to lists. be cautious there.

Start with the below content in `datain.txt` and the program given below will replicate and demonstrate with more records

```
[
    (170,572,380,114,-17746,[('F',3),('b',19)]),
    (170,222,128,40,-7086,[('F',3),('b',4),('g',2)]),
    (170,184,52,18,-5776,[('F',3),('b',1),('g',1),('C',2)])
]
```

Here is the full code demonstrating speeds of dumping and loading with `pickle` and `json`

```
import time
import json
import pickle

def main():
    '''The Main'''

    with open('datain.txt') as f:
        # Load 3 records
        start = time.time()
        data = eval(" ".join(f.readlines()))
        end = time.time()
        print(f'Loading {len(data)} records took {end - start} seconds')

        # Replicate 1M records
        start = time.time()
        for _ in range(100000):
            data.append(data[0])
        end = time.time()
        print(f'Replicating {len(data)} records took {end - start} seconds\n')


        # Print the file as text
        start = time.time()
        with open('data.txt', 'w') as fw:
            fw.write(str(data))
        end = time.time()
        print(f'Printing {len(data)} records took {end - start} seconds')

        # read the file as text and eval
        start = time.time()
        with open('data.txt', 'r') as fr:
            dataNew = eval(" ".join(fr.readlines()))
        end = time.time()
        print(f'Loading and evaluating {len(dataNew)} records took {end - start} seconds')
        print(dataNew[0], "\n")


        # Pickle dump the file
        start = time.time()
        pickle.dump(data, open('data.p', 'wb'))
        end = time.time()
        print(f'Pickle dumping {len(data)} records took {end - start} seconds')

        # unpickle the file
        start = time.time()
        dataNew = pickle.load(open('data.p', 'rb'))
        end = time.time()
        print(f'Pickle loading {len(dataNew)} records took {end - start} seconds')
        print(dataNew[0], "\n")


        # JSON dump the file
        start = time.time()
        json.dump(data, open('data.json', 'w'))
        end = time.time()
        print(f'JSON Dumping {len(data)} records took {end - start} seconds')

        # JSON load the file
        start = time.time()
        dataNew = json.load(open('data.json', 'r'))
        end = time.time()
        print(f'JSON Loading {len(dataNew)} records took {end - start} seconds')
        print(dataNew[0], "\n")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here is the output

```
Loading 3 records took 0.00022935867309570312 seconds
Replicating 100003 records took 0.011992931365966797 seconds

Printing 100003 records took 0.24912047386169434 seconds
Loading and evaluating 100003 records took 4.48364782333374 seconds
(170, 572, 380, 114, -17746, [('F', 3), ('b', 19)]) 

Pickle dumping 100003 records took 0.006680965423583984 seconds
Pickle loading 100003 records took 0.017989397048950195 seconds
(170, 572, 380, 114, -17746, [('F', 3), ('b', 19)]) 

JSON Dumping 100003 records took 1.446699857711792 seconds
JSON Loading 100003 records took 0.3919186592102051 seconds
[170, 572, 380, 114, -17746, [['F', 3], ['b', 19]]]
```

Comment: choosing between json object and the python object with tuple, which one would perform better when the record size is huge?

Comment: As it appears above pickle is good for your data. Lists are mutable, tuple is not. so tuples is fast if you do not plan to add elements to them later